# How do I change login account on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I have a GMail account (aa@gmail.com) and I always log in with this account on Stack Overflow.

Now,I was forbidden to use this aa@gmail.com account but I can use new account(bb@gmail.com) .

**I treasure my reputations and badges on Stack Overflow.**

Therefore, when I use Stack Overflow, I want to get my reputations of aa@gmail.com by logging in with bb@gmail.com.

Can I change login account on Stack Overflow?

Comment: What do you mean "forbidden to use this account"? If you can't ask any more questions it's for a good reason, otherwise please explain.

Comment: If one of your accounts was banned then why shouldn't you lose the rep and badges earnt with it?

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't very clear...

> Now,I was forbidden to use this aa@gmail.com account but I can use new account(bb@gmail.com)

Were you forbidden by the team? What specifically happens which makes you say you were "forbidden"? It *sounds* like your best solution is to email `team@stackoverflow.com`.

Now, assuming that **you were not suspended** and you simply want to change your login accounts, keeping your rep and badges, you can edit the logins / open IDs you use on your account on your profile:

[image: profile fhs]

Again, I'm not clear on what you're asking, this may not be of any use to you. If you're unable to log in to `aa@gmail.com` then you can't link with that account... So let me again refer you to `team@stackoverflow.com` if you're stuck.